# functionality similar to ACF repeater? User to add points

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have custom post type called "tours" , user adds post called "london tour" as a title .   And then i want user to be able to add tour stops, which will be displayed in front end with fontawesome icons , as a stylised list . I don't want to include full text editor, just some kind of field with ability to add next field, and then display them by looping through them .

My only though was to have a simple list in content editor, and to use javascript to stylize 'li' items etc.

Comment: Why not just use ACF repeater?

Comment: @paul well because i'm learning wp development and because it costs money :)

Comment: Ok fair enough I used this tutorial years ago and used these meta boxes for a long time but found it's hard to maintain and ACF is really worth the investment. The tutorial still gives a good idea on repeaters although some of it is outdated such as the old Wordpress media uploader I'm pretty sure some of it doesn't work properly but there's still some decent info in it, worth a look: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields--wp-23259